# Eclipse SVN: After commit changes to server, local copy remais on previous version

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I checked out the version 210 of an app from SVN server, did some changes and commit it back to server. No problems here.

Opening the SVN History, I see a new version, 212, but mut my local copy still 210 (!?).

How can I make my local copy be updated automatically? This behavior is causing too many problems!

I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 1):

The SVN documentation is clear: the commit and update operations are atomic. After a commit, you need to make a update.